# Autorole discord bot python

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Alright, what I need is to put autorole code to my bot but only for *specific* server.
**So please, help me!**
Here is the code so far but I made it only beacuse stack overflow can't accept my text body:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member : discord.Member):
    server = ctx.message.server
    rolelol = client.get_role('770262439937048577')
    if server == server.id:('753667215710224574'):
        await client.add_roles(member, rolelol)
    else:
        await client.say('')
```

All I need is code for autorole this doesn't code i made doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things wrong :

- [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) is a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member) object method, so you have to use `member.add_roles()`
- `ctx` isn't defined since you're not in a command, to get the discord [guild object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild), you have to write `member.guild`
- [`get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role) is a [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild) object method so you need to write `member.guild.get_role(id)`
- Your IDs need to be passed as `int`, not `str`.
- [`Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client) objects don't have any `say()` method

With all thoses changes, your code would look like this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member : discord.Member):
    role = member.guild.get_role(770262439937048577)
    if member.guild.id == 753667215710224574:
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Reference : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/