# Discord.py autorole not working on new members

Tags: python, discord.py

My code should be perfectly fine but whenever I leave and rejoin a server on discord, it doesn't rank me to the role I need. The role is also all correct, below is the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = #I'm not placing my token for security reasons
BOT_PREFIX = '>'
ROLE = 'A1'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name = ROLE)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print(f"{member} was given {role}")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

May someone tell me what went wrong and how I should fix it, thanks!

Comment: Your answer is already in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367808/autorole-discord-bot-python

Comment: You most likely are missing intents. `Guild.roles` require [`discord.Intents.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.guilds) to be enabled in your bot. You can read more about intents here - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: You also need the Member privileged intent https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents

Comment: Hey @AliFGT , I tried that before and it still doesn't work.